# How to validate dynamic route in middleware.js - next js

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering, middleware, next.js13

This is my folder structure

[image]

I am trying to write code in middleware.js so that country_code should be either US or CA. Also [state_code] should be always NY or FL.

When I printed request.nextUrl, I could not find any variable pointing to the dynamic route.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.nextUrl.searchParams))
    // return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/[country_code]')) {
        console.log("hi")
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
    }

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
    ],
}
```

Kindly assist me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is a good feature in sveltekit called [param matcher](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing). next.js does not have it yet but since it follows sveltekit, I think it will eventually add this feature.

currently you can read it with

```
// this will return string
const pathname=req.nextUrl.pathname
// it will be /route1/country_code_id
// convert this to an array using split()
const splittedPathname=pathname.split("/")
// result will be ['', 'route1', 'country_code_id']
// add validation if index 2 exist
const dynamicID=splittedPathname[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the path match from [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#conditional-statements) doc

Looks like it has some [issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/16y556p/regular_expression_for_matcher_doesnt_seem_to_work/),

If I understand correctly country code is your starting dynamic path, Please try this way it works for me

```
 !!request.nextUrl.pathname.match('/(.*)/page5/(.*)')
```